# How to depend on Bean from starter module in an application's Configuration?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a custom spring boot starter that defines some bean via autoconfiguration depending on a configuration property being present or not:

```java
// MyProperty.java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.feature")
public MyProperty record(String someKey) {}

// MyAutoConfiguration.java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyFeatureProperties.class)
public class MyAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.feature")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(MyFeatureConfiguration.class)
    public MyFeatureConfiguration myFeatureConfiguration(MyProperty property) {
        return new MyFeatureConfiguration(property);
    }
}
```

Then in `META-INF/spring.factories` I have

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
my.package.MyAutoConfiguration
```

A spring boot application has a dependency on the above mentioned starter artifact.
Within the application I want to define a bean that depends on the bean coming from the starter but it should only be created if the starter bean is present:

```java
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyApplicationBean myService(MyFeatureConfiguration config) {
        return new MyApplicationBean(config);
    }
}
```

So my question is how can this dependecy be solved?

I tried using @ConditionalOnBean but this did not work since, if I understand correctly, the application's @Configuration classes are processed before autoconfigurations, and therefore MyFeatureConfiguration is not present.